# where does trace $\sigma$-algebra come from

Tags: set-theory

I came across the term trace $\sigma$-algebra in the context of conditional probability. Does anyone know where it comes from? i found a reference to trace of a matrix here: https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Miller/mathword/ but that was it.

Comment: I guess  you mean this https://wiki.unifiedmathematics.com/index.php?title=Trace_sigma-algebra  "Trace" in this sense is not related to "trace" of a matrix.  "Trace" of a matrix is translation of the German word "Spur".  I do not know the origin of "trace" for sigma-algebra.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar In this context German "Spur" is a cognate of English "Spoor", which means trace or track (of an animal one is hunting). "Remnant" is, I think, an acceptable translation, and not  inappropriate for this connotation.

Comment: It's a bit of mystery then. Maybe someone who knows will spot this in the million other things on this site and drop a line.

Comment: The question [Origin of the term 'Trace Topology'](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2024179/origin-of-the-term-trace-topology) also found no trace (ouch) of the origin of a closely related term.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley. You are forgiven your tracegression because of your efforts to track down the answer.  I am certain someone out there knows the answer but how to draw their eyeballs to this spot?